# stem cells divisions and normal cells division

Tags: cell-biology

I'm a beginner in biology, but I've read that stem cells replace the "worn out" cells or the dead cells. Well, I'm a bit confused - why do they do this?
Aren't there any cells nearby which are the same type as the worn out cells or the dead ones, that can divide and so on?